# How do I find an specific textbox in the same row of a HTML table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I was hoping someone could help me here. It *seems* like it should be easy but I have not been able to find a solution.

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I've attached a a javascript function to the `onclick` event handler of the `CheckBox`controls on the far left. Here is my javascript:

```
// Toggle row colors when a "N/A" checkbox is clicked.
function handleNAClick(cb) {
    if ($(cb).parent().parent().hasClass('silver')) {
        $(cb).parent().parent().removeClass('silver').addClass('white');
    }
    else {
        $(cb).parent().parent().removeClass('white').addClass('silver');
    }
}
```

This function toggles the row color when the `CheckBox` is clicked.

What I want to be able to do is also enable/disable the `TextBox` at the far right of the row if the `CheckBox` is clicked.

This table is dynamically generated and I don't know the ID of the controls ahead of time.

As you can see, I can already get a handle to the table row and change the color, but for some reason I can't figure out how to get a handle to the `TextBox` on that row.

From my research this should work for enabling the textbox in jQuery, but it doesn't:

```
$(cb).parent().parent().find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
```

I can't even change the text in the `TextBox` either:

```
$(cb).parent().parent().find('input').val('hotdog');
```

Seems like it should be simple so I'm inclined to think I'm "fat-fingering" it somehow.

Does anyone know of a better way to do what I want? What am I messing up?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: Are those input boxes or text areas? Input boxes don't usually have scrollbars

Comment: Looks like `<textarea/>`s instead of `<input/>`s...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are using `<textarea>` instead of `<input>`, if this is the case the following will work:

```
$(cb).parents('tr:first').find('textarea').prop('disabled', false);
```

Since you want to *modify* the property of an element it has to be done via `.prop()` method, removing the attribute will no do anything.

Comment: Yes! This is the answer. Thank you for your help! I'm almost embarrassed it was that easy to answer. I'll get over it. :)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and easy solution, it seems like you're on the right track. You simply have to get the right combination of dom traversal methods to find what you're looking for. Are you sure the cells on the far right of your table are simple inputs? It looks more like a textarea but I can't tell. In general, try and move away from this system though, what if later you need to add another column or a wrapper div? It might be worth your while to modify the dynamic generation code a little to help aid you.